# Versioning in Java Web Start

Tags: jnlp, java-web-start

does someone know what to specify in the JNLP file so that JARS won't be downloaded all the time, but only when there's a new version on the server side? I know i can specify: version="1.5" for exactly the version 1.5, or version="1.6+" for 1.6 or higher.

Let's take the case of version="1.6+". If the user has version 1.7 a JAR won't be downloaded, even if on the server the JAR keeps updating to 1.8, 1.9 and so on... I want the JAR to be downloaded but only when there's a new version on the server side. Can this be done?

Thanks,
Teo

Answer (score 4):

> what to specify in the JNLP file so that JARS won't be downloaded all the time, but only when there's a new version on the server side

By default webstart will check if you have the latest version of every jar file referenced in your JNLP. To avoid these often unnecessary checks, you can use the "version download protocol" .

You first need to name your application resources (jars etc) using the following naming convention
`<name of jar file>__V<version number>.jar`
Next, you need to add the `version` attribute to the `<jar>` tag and then you version-enable your resources by setting the `jnlp.versionEnabled` to true in the JNLP.

This method will ensure that only the outdated jars are updated.

Details are given [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html)

If, however, you do not wish to change your JNLP to modify the version numbers of the jars that have changed, then this option will NOT work for you and you will have to deal with default behavior of the WebStart that checks each an every resource to verify that you have the latest version.

Comment: I'm already using version.xml for the versioning, but this is not my problem. The problem is: how to make it always have the latest version of the JAR without constantly changing the JNLP to ask for the latest version of the JAR?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i think i missed something in that page. I will test this!

Comment: I understand... But is there a way to have fresh JARs without constantly changing the JNLP or always downloading JAR resources no matter what? It seems to me this versioning protocol is only doing half the job because it does not push new versions to the client...

Comment: @Teo :Even my jnlp file is getting downloaded every time i click in browser, i want javaws to launch cached jnlp file if same version is available.jnlp file name is **test.jnlp** so next time **test-1.jnlp** is created in **Temp** folder